# digitalocean and cloud9 ssh connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, cloud9-ide, digital-ocean

I'm having problems joining cloud9's workspace with the directory on digitalOcean machine that is listened by nginx and unicorn (home/rails). It seems that it doesn't exist when using cloud9 in-console. Have anyone dealt with similar issue?

Best Regards, Kacper

Answer (score 2):

OK, looks like you need a [paid account](https://c9.io/web/site/pricing) to use SSH.
I'll just have to go with SFTP to connect with my droplet.

Answer (score 0):

You must install nodejs server in your machine because cloud 9 use it to run in any system. Checkout their tutorial on [how to do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xld1JXd70aY) and of course you have the right to create one ssh work space in c9 with your free account.